# I want to change the status bar to other white but dark i want to change to black

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change the status bar to other blue but dark i want to change to black.
I tried to change it in here [image]

However, it wasn't working.
Next I learnt that
I Change this [image]

It's working!
But when i change to the dark mode,it is always white, but I want it will be black!
Could you help me?
PS: Had better not use any other libraries.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new resource directory named `values-night`, copy your `themes.xml` to that directory and change the color to black there.